# Reversing and printing out the contents of an array using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I need to reverse and print out the contents of the following array using recursion:

```
int myArray[] = { 65, 89, 74, 25, 21, 54, 38, 64, 11, 45, 19, 48, 46, 83 };
```

The call to the function is:

```
printArray(myArray, arraySize, 0, arraySize - 1);
```

And my function is:

```
void printArray(int values[], int sizeOfArray, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int tempValue = values[low];
        values[low] = values[high];
        values[high] = tempValue;
        printArray(values,sizeOfArray, low+1 ,high-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
        cout << values[i]<<' ';
    }
}
```

The output that I am getting is the reversed array a total of 8 times.

```
83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65 83 46 48 19 45 11 64 38 54 21 25 74 89 65
```

I can not seem to figure out what is wrong here. I am also new to arrays and recursion so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are iterating through your array, at every level of the recursion. Did you try first invoking the function, and then, printing out the results?

Comment: explain your idea!

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop in a recursive function?

Comment: Put in `if (low == 0) {...}` surrounding your for-loop. Then recheck your assignment requirements. Chances are you're supposed to reverse the array, *then* print it, but not necessarily in the *same* function. If it is supposed to be in the same function, then triggering your print loop only once (at the tail of the most outer invoke using the if-test I showed) will do it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so far it is the only way I have learned to print an array

Comment: @WhozCraig that worked, if you want to submit it as an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same function is supposed reverse, then print, the sequence, you can do it by surrounding your for-loop with a condition that is only true on the outer-most invoke of the recursive call stack.

```
void printArray(int values[], int sizeOfArray, int low, int high) 
{
    if (low < high) 
    {
        int tempValue = values[low];
        values[low] = values[high];
        values[high] = tempValue;
        printArray(values, sizeOfArray, low+1 ,high-1);
    }
    if (low == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
            std::cout << values[i]<<' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

Worth noting. `sizeofArray`, or `high`, are pointless in this code. You don't need both. You can just as easily do this, for example:

```
void printArray(int values[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int tempValue = values[low];
        values[low] = values[high];
        values[high] = tempValue;
        printArray(values, low+1 ,high-1);
    }
    if (low == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= high; i++)
            std::cout << values[i]<<' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Or

Likewise, you can use a template to do this to gather the native array size at compile time (which I leave as a future exercise, as right now it would probably be more a Rube Goldberg solution to you than anything else).